# Spring JMS Outbound Gateway receive timeout being ignored

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a Spring Integration flow which sends a message out via a JMS Outbound Gateway which is configured to have a receive timeout of 45 seconds. I am trying to test the receive timeout period by sending a message out in a setup where the message is never consumed on the other side (therefore a response doesn't come back). However, when I run the test, the message is placed in the outbound queue but, the Outbound Gateway's receive timeout never occurs (after 45 seconds). Any ideas what reasons there could be for this happening (not happening)?

My stack is:

```
o.s.i:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.0.M3
o.s.i:spring-integration-jms:4.0.4.RELEASE
```

My IntegrationgConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("test.request.ch")
            .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                    .receiveTimeout(45000)
                    .requestDestination("REQUEST_QUEUE")
                    .replyDestination("RESPONSE_QUEUE")
                    .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID"))
            .handle("testService",
                    "testMethod")
            .channel("test.response.ch").get();
    }

    ...
}
```

In terms of JMS configuration, the connection factory used is a standard CachingConnectionFactory which targets an MQConnectionFactory.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.
PM

--- UPDATE ---

I have turned on debugging and I can see that when the timeout occurs the following message is logged:

```
AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler - handler 'org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#0' produced no reply for request Message: [Payload byte[835]][...]
```

Just need to find out how to capture this event in the flow?

--- UPDATE 2 ---

The message being sent out has an ERROR_CHANNEL header set on it to which I would expect the timeout exception to be routed to - but this routing does not happen?

Is it possible that the CachingConnectionFactory is handling the exception and not passing it back to the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it working you need to add the second Lambda to the `.handle()` with `Jms`:

```
.handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                .receiveTimeout(45000)
                .requestDestination("REQUEST_QUEUE")
                .replyDestination("RESPONSE_QUEUE")
                .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID"),
        e -> e.requiresReply(true))
```

By default `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` doesn't require `reply` even if `receiveTimeout` is exhausted, and we see that by logs shown by you.

However, I see that we should revise all `MessageHandlerSpec`s, because XML support changes the `requires-reply` for some components to `true` by default.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) on the matter and we'll address it soon, because the `GA` release for Java DSL is planned over a week or two: https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/31/spring-integration-java-dsl-1-0-rc1-released

Thank you for the attention to this stuff!

Comment: Hi @Artem, that's worked nicely. I'll raise a JIRA as requested. Thanks!